# Cache router in Django - how to run python manage.py createcachetable properly for the related database

Tags: python, django, caching

I am using Django for my project.

I need to generate a new cache table in the database.

The command `python manage.py createcachetable` doesn't work for db_my_project instead it works for the default one.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'db_my_project': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'my_db', 
        'USER': 'my_username',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password',,
        'HOST': 'my_host',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
}
```

I have the following cache settings in the settings.py:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'dataframe_cache',
    }
}
```

As you can see above from its location info, it is supposed to generate a the table 'dataframe_cache'. It is generating that table for the default database (db.sqlite3), but not for the db_my_project (mysql).

I know that I should implement a cache router class like below.

```
class CacheRouter:
    """A router to control all database cache operations"""

    route_app_labels = {'db_my_project'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'db_my_project'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'django_cache':
            return 'db_my_project'
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'db_my_project'
        return None
```

My question is that where do I put this CacheRouter class in my Django project so that I can generate a new table for the cache using the `python manage.py createcachetable` command?

Comment: Have you added a `DATABASE_ROUTERS` setting for `CacheRouter`?

Comment: I have the DATABASE_ROUTERS in my settings.py file but what do you mean for CacheRouter?

Comment: You have to add cacherouter in database routers afaik

Comment: So, `DATABASE_ROUTERS = [..., 'path.to. CacheRouter']` and then `python manage.py createcachetable --database=db_my_project`

Comment: Okay, but when I use the cache.set and cache.get methods, how can I make them see the db_my_project? It is always checking the default one.

Comment: Can you add how you use the cache in a view for example?

Comment: Also can you confirm that its still checking default even after adding the routers and the management command?

Comment: Wavv, actually the cache.set and cache.get methods are working now after this DATABASE_ROUTERS settings. Thanks a lot.